# set Geany to work with Anaconda

Tags: python, geany, anaconda

How would you configure Geany so that it works with Anaconda.

I have both installed and running separately, but these two kids won't work hand in hand as I would want them to do..

I have tried many different setting in Geany, changed paths, used VTE output or not, changed the Set Build Command setting, nothing has worked yet.

More concretely, when I try to `import numpy` I get a `No module named numpy error`

If anyone can give me a hint, I would be really gratefull :)

Btw I am using Python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**
Please check in *Build -> Set Build Commands*, if Geany is calling the default python interpreter. For example in that dialog in execute commands default is *python "%f"* if you want to use the python3 interpreter you need to change it to *~/anaconda/bin/python3 "%f"* (check the route for your anaconda installation) more info about anaconda IDE setup: [ide_integration](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration)

Comment: Simply changing the buildcommand to python "%f" worked for me.  Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit) on linux